# How do I use files in the Chrome file storage in javascript for images src's, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

In my chrome app, I've successfully downloaded image files from the network and stored them in the Chrome App persistent filesystem storage.

For example, the app might download a file named foo.png and store it in the file system with that same name. The app is then able to read the file from the file system using the same name. However, if the javascript tries to set the 'src' on an  using the same name it fails:

```
$('#image').attr('src', 'foo.png');
```

If instead, I read the file and store its contents in a blob, then use the blobURL it works. However, if instead of an image, I'm setting the src for an iFrame, and the contents of the iFrame have links to other assets, the app fails to load the other assets (as it doesn't seem able to access the assets with their vanilla file names).

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times already, and is also well documented by Google in their Chrome App docs (look for the part about CSP). For an SO example, this one is a good as any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280428/how-to-show-images-in-other-domains-chrome-packaged-apps

Comment: Are you changing the src attribute of a <td> element? Since src is not recognized for td.